# Why Search APi detect wrong SOLR host?

Tags: 7, search

Configuration view:

[image]

As you can see Search API uses site base url as SOLR host which is obviously wrong...

Comment: Some first thoughts: Do you have a base path set in .htaccess? Are you overwriting settings in settings.php using the `$conf` array? Does the string "j.dev" occur anywhere in your code?

Comment: None of the above. Configuration from apachesolr module at admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings works ok

Comment: @marcvangend I think search api servers are ctools plugins or similar, their values can't be overwritten through variables IIRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, localhost replaced by $_SERVER['name'] value is only for presentation purposes. More info here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2512986

I had other issue with SOLR, so that's why it didn't work